# Непонятная ошибка в переменных

Tags: javascript

Есть кусок кода :

```
function Actions(name,args){
    this.args = args;
    this.get_name = () => turn[this.args.target];
    this.copy = () => {
        this.args.card.copy = true;
        console.log("copy : "+copy);
        for(let i = 0;i<this.args.count;i++){
            let k = copy(this.args.card);
            this.get_name().take_card(k);
        }
    };
//some code
}
```

Есть функция **copy** (глубокая копия объекта), есть **свойство copy** у объекта card (true || false).

Почему **copy**, который идет ниже присвоения:

```
this.args.card.copy = true ;
```

воспринимается как **свойство copy** объекта card, а не как функция **copy**?

Причем если сместить присвоение вниз, то все работает нормально...

P.S.

```
function copy(arr){
    if(arr.length){
        var arr1 = [];
    }else if(typeof arr == "object"){
        var arr1 = {};
    }else{
        return arr; 
    }
    for(let key in arr){
        if(typeof arr[key] == "function" || typeof arr[key] != "object")
            arr1[key] = arr[key];
        else 
            arr1[key] = copy(arr[key],true);
    }
    return arr1;
}
```

P.S.S. 
Почему copy 1 - функция, а copy 2 - true?

```
//
/*1*/console.log(copy); // copy - функция
this.args.card.copy = true; 
/*2*/console.log(copy) // copy - true
//
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. А что вы ожидаете в console.log?

Comment: Ожидаю увидеть там функцию copy, а не true.

Comment: Я тоже ничего не понял.

Comment: где и как это все вызывается?

Comment: Есть html-объект, к нему привязан объект card, при, допустим, нажатии на него, вызывается функция" this.play = function(){for(let key in this.actions)this.actions[key]();}"; (this == card) ;в this.actions лежат методы описанные выше.

Comment: "Главное заблуждение человечества - каждый думает, что говорит понятно."

Comment: @Igor, прям в точку...

Comment: @Air Это не я, Виктор Суворов, "Очищение" - "Первое заблуждение человечества: каждому кажется, что он говорит понятно."

Answer (score 1):

В args.card я случайно отправлял объект window, т.е. я заменял свою функцию copy на значение true.

Comment: Молодец, что нашел и сообщил об этом! В вопросе все равно не хватает воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: У меня там сложная система с объектами, строк на 700, думаю не очень целесообразно приводить столь большие примеры.

Comment: @Frog, правильно, нужно выкинуть все лишнее и несущественное, и предоставить минимальный пример